# How to migrate gitlab-ce 13(linux install) to gitlab-ee 16(docker image)

Tags: docker, migration, gitlab

I am trying to migrate gitlab server to latest version.

current using version is `ce-13.12.3` and want to upgrade to `ee-16.4` docker image(https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ee/tags)

The goals I want to achieve is

- migrate config(gitlab.rb)
- migrate data

And I got

- backup settings in departure gitlab-ce

  - also have backup data

The problem is gitlab official document said ["You can only restore a backup to exactly the same version and type (CE or EE) of GitLab on which it was created"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/backup_restore/restore_gitlab.html#the-destination-gitlab-instance-must-have-the-exact-same-version). Further more, the [official site](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/backup_restore/restore_gitlab.html#the-destination-gitlab-instance-must-have-the-exact-same-version) does not serve 13.12.3 documents.(At the right end of the header menu)

The only method I can imagine is

- install docker ce-13.12.3 image and migrate data
- migrate every step(13 to 14, to 15, to 16)
- convert base image gitlab/gitlab-ce to gitlab/gitlab-ee

  - (expect) install and running ee image with same version of ce config and data

But before I try this, I want to know are there alternative methods available.